# Xamarin Android Java Bindings Library .aar CS0102 The type 'EventEventArgs' already contains a definition for 'p0'

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

```
// event args for com.elotouch.library.EloPeripheralEventListener.onEvent
public partial class EventEventArgs : global::System.EventArgs {

    public EventEventArgs (int p0)
    {
        this.p0 = p0;
    }

    int p0;
    public int P0 {
        get { return p0; }
    }
}
```

// event args for com.elotouch.library.EloPeripheralEventListener.onEvent
public partial class EventEventArgs : global::System.EventArgs {

```
    public EventEventArgs (int p0, int p1)
    {
        this.p0 = p0;
        this.p1 = p1;
    }

    int p0;
    public int P0 {
        get { return p0; }
    }

    int p1;
    public int P1 {
        get { return p1; }
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't a question. Be specific and imagine you’re asking a question to another person. What are you trying to do, what are your expected results, what errors/results do you get, what have you already tried?

Comment: @IsmaelCarrasco I'm facing the same issue trying to create a binding for the elo SDK. did you get any further?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to transform some method names by using the `metadata.xml` [Docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/customizing-bindings/java-bindings-metadata)
this is how I did it

```
<metadata>
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.elotouch.library']/interface[@name='EloPeripheralEventListener']/method[@name='onEvent']" name="managedName">OnListenerEvent</attr>
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.elotouch.library']/interface[@name='EloPeripheralEventListener']/method[@name='onEvent' and count(parameter)=1]" name="managedName">OnListenerEventOne</attr>
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.elotouch.library']/interface[@name='EloPeripheralEventListener']/method[@name='onEvent' and count(parameter)=2]" name="managedName">OnListenerEventTwo</attr>
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.elotouch.library']/interface[@name='EloPeripheralEventListener']/method[@name='onEvent' and count(parameter)=2 and parameter[2][@type='java.lang.String']]" name="managedName">OnListenerEventThree</attr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would complete @Joe B answer with the following code sample :

```
    // Metadata.xml XPath interface reference: path="/api/package[@name='mylib.android.core.service']/interface[@name='Poker.SessionServiceLifecycleListener']"
    [Register ("mylib/android/core/service/Poker$SessionServiceLifecycleListener", "", "mylib.Android.Core.Service.Poker/ISessionServiceLifecycleListenerInvoker")]
    public partial interface ISessionServiceLifecycleListener : IJavaObject, IJavaPeerable {
        // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='mylib.android.core.service']/interface[@name='Poker.SessionServiceLifecycleListener']/method[@name='onServiceConnected' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='mylib.android.core.service.Poker.SessionService']]"
        [Register ("onServiceConnected", "(Lmylib/android/core/service/Poker$SessionService;)V", "GetOnServiceConnected_Lmylib_android_core_service_Poker_SessionService_Handler:mylib.Android.Core.Service.Poker/ISessionServiceLifecycleListenerInvoker, Poker-AAR-to-DONET")]
        void OnServiceConnected (global::mylib.Android.Core.Service.Poker.ISessionService? p0);
    }


    //...


    // event args for mylib.android.core.service.Poker.SessionServiceLifecycleListener.onServiceConnected
    public partial class ServiceConnectedEventArgs : global::System.EventArgs {
        public ServiceConnectedEventArgs (global::mylib.Android.Core.Service.Poker.ISessionService? p0)
        {
            this.p0 = p0;
        }

        global::mylib.Android.Core.Service.Poker.ISessionService? p0;

        public global::mylib.Android.Core.Service.Poker.ISessionService? P0 {
            get { return p0; }
        }

    }
```

The following error occurs

```
The type 'ServiceConnectedEventArgs' already contains a definition for 'p0' (CS0102)
```

The following metadata fix the issue (it is not natural to modify the ISessionServiceLifecycleListener whereas the error occurs from ServiceConnectedEventArgs)...

```
<metadata>
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='mylib.android.core.service']/interface[@name='Poker.SessionServiceLifecycleListener']/method[@name='onServiceConnected' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='mylib.android.core.service.Poker.SessionService']]/parameter[@name='p0']"
            name="managedName">sessionService</attr>
</metadata>
```